# Is there any way to edit own website template using free any website builder?

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting

Please provide me any good free webhosting site with site builder using own templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your skill-set, this may be a (somewhat) difficult exercise, but it is the best that I can suggest, since you're looking for free hosting + website builder + own/custom templates etc.

You could try the Amazon AWS t2.micro free tire instance (free for one year). However, the instance will need to be setup and configured for web hosting (with the LAMP/LEMP stack etc.) If you're comfortable with Linux system admin (via ssh) etc., it could be a great option:

https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Once the instance is up and running with a basic Linux distro, you could speed up the rest of the setup by installing the (cool, open source) [VestaCP](http://vestacp.com/) hosting admin panel (it will automatically install the entire LEMP stack + several other essential/useful tools, services and some other bells and whistles etc. for you):

http://vestacp.com/

(Or else, you could always install LA/EMP manually as well.)

Once this is done, your t2.micro instance would become a (powerful, cloud VPS) hosting server and you would be ready to add your domain/s to it.

At this point, you can install any open source/free website builder and/or any CMS like [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org), [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/), [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) etc. and host/build out your site/s using any free/custom/other templates.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions !!